# Better SIESTA workflows system?

Tags: software-recommendations, atomic-simulation-environment, siesta

Normally, I run all my SIESTA calculations manually and then go to post-processing the results, also manually.

I would like to know which of the tools below is "better" (more complete?) in order to make a more efficient use of time when using SIESTA.

- [Atomic Simulation Environment](https://wiki.fysik.dtu.dk/ase/index.html)
- [AiiDA](https://www.aiida.net/index.html)
- [SISL](https://zerothi.github.io/sisl/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This answer is based on the current state of things (and will likely change rather quickly).

In the following I differentiate between a *workflow* and *post-processing*.

**workflow**:
A workflow is, IMHO, something that utilises automation. I.e. one submits a job with a workflow scheme, that then does everything for you.

**post-processing**:
A manual labor interaction with the software.

#### ASE

This just got an overhaul very recently [end of February 2024]:

- https://gitlab.com/ase/ase/-/merge_requests/3269
- https://gitlab.com/ase/ase/-/merge_requests/3270
- https://gitlab.com/ase/ase/-/merge_requests/3271
- https://gitlab.com/ase/ase/-/merge_requests/3272
- https://gitlab.com/ase/ase/-/merge_requests/3273
- https://gitlab.com/ase/ase/-/merge_requests/3278
- https://gitlab.com/ase/ase/-/merge_requests/3279

(likely I missed a few).

The current status of the ASE interface is that it should work stable against the coming Siesta 5 release. This is the aim.

I would call the current ASE implementation *very* stable with the above things. However, do note that this hasn't been released yet.

The ASE implementation is a rather simple way of dealing with workflows, it still requires some manual labor for managing the workflows, so if you are looking for highly automated workflows with thousands of runs, then I would not suggest going this route.

ASE implements a very limited output parsing.
It can read the some output energies, bandstructure information, fermi-level and some `PAO.Basis` block settings.

But that is more or less it.

#### AiiDA

The Siesta AiiDA implementation can be found [here](https://docs.siesta-project.org/projects/aiida-siesta/en/latest/workflows/index.html).

The AiiDA interface backend is developed with the coming Siesta 5 release. AFAIK it can do things that ASE can't do, and vice versa.

AiiDA is really based on doing a large number of calculations in a *proper* workflow. I.e. the AiiDA database will store input and output files so one can always grab the information from a particular run.
This complexity is extremely useful when doing thousands of systematic calculations where one can automate a lot of the processes.

It can still be used for single runs, but the learning curve for AiiDA, I would argue, is a bit steeper than ASE.

So, bottom line, AiiDA is really great for large systematic calculations. It might also be useful for smaller things such as single system investigations, but it requires more of the user. :)

For post-processing data, AiiDA also offers a limited set of interaction points.
It can also do bandgap analysis, system convergence among other things.
But they are tightly bound in the code-base, and might be a bit difficult to extend (not an expert, so I might be wrong!).

#### sisl

Disclaimer: Author of sisl

sisl is never meant to be a workflow engine.
Its inception was about the idea of allowing users to easily script post-processing utilities. As such it focuses on handling the *output* of calculations in a very stringent manner.

For instance sisl allows one to read

- *any* of the grid output variables, `RHO`, `DRHO`, `LDOS`, `VT`, `VH`, ...
- Hamiltonian and overlap matrices, can post-process it to generate band-structures
- Density matrices, can post-process to calculate Mulliken and other kinds of charges
- reads in basis-set information and allows one to expand density-matrices to real-space grids
- reads forces from `FA` files
- parses bands file outputs
- parses `PDOS` output files (with command-line-interfaces for plotting)
- reads (I think) all the geometry output file formats
- can parse the SCF cycle in a very detailed manner, e.g. check convergence of the SCF cycle by extracting dD/Hmax and other values.
- sisl is not *only* Siesta based. It also tries to parse output files from other programs, these are not as sufficiently developed, but if there is a use-case and a PR, it will be appreciated :)

On top of the above, it can manipulate the output data in many different ways.

sisl also has an advance plotting facility, build around `plotly` which can do pretty advanced things (attribute to @pol-febrer).

All of the above can be done in *scripting* mode in Python, but other more simple things can be done via the command-line:

```shell
# Plot (via matplotlib) the PDOS data
sdata siesta.PDOS --plot [options for selecting atoms etc. is available]
# Create a cube file of the charge-density difference from a reference charge-density
sgrid reference/Rho.grid.nc --diff Rho.grid.nc --geometry RUN.fdf --out diff.cube
```

There are many more options.

sisl is tightly following Siesta, and it is usable with older versions, and the coming Siesta 5 release.

For everyday post-processing I would argue that sisl is the more complete package. sisl is not meant to *be* a workflow, it is meant for users to create workflows around it. So if you want some kind of workflow, then using sisl underneath might be a good choice.